# I'm looking for navigation bar like with in flutter please guide me if you know

Tags: flutter, uinavigationbar

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SkP8V.png)
I'm looking for navigation bar like with in flutter please guide me if you know

Answer (score 0):

Looks like **style15** from this library

[image]

[persistent_bottom_nav_bar](https://pub.dev/packages/persistent_bottom_nav_bar)

You can upgrade it, and then it will be fine.